# Firebase - Filter by a column

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using Firebase for my Angular.js application.

I'm looking for the equivalent of SQL's `WHERE` statement for Firebase.

I have an array of TV series stored in Firebase, and I want to fetch only these that has the name that the user entered (in the example `searchQuery`).

Does Firebase support it? Does it have something like this?

```js
var seriesRef = new Firebase('http://{app}.firebaseio.com/series');
var seriesObject = $firebaseObject(seriesRef.query({ name: searchQuery }));
```

Comment: Since the `series` is a collection, why are you trying to get rid of `$firebaseArray`? It seems to me like that it the right class to use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have some suggestions that may help here:

- Check out the [Firebase Query documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/). Specifically,

  - [`.orderByChild()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html)
  - [`.equalTo()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html)
- You can use queries in conjunction with [`.$ref()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-ref) to get the desired record.

### Example

- Check out this working [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/sbolel/pen/abmXZQe).

  - I replicated your data in one of my public Firebase instances.
  - The query that you're looking for is `seriesCollectionRef.orderByChild('name').equalTo(seriesName)`
  - If you enter '`Avatar: The Last Airbender`' in the input and click "Find", you'll get the matching series object.
- In my example, I extended the `$firebaseArray` service to include a method for finding a specific series by name.

  - See the documentation for [extending AngularFire services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-services).
  - You can accomplish the same thing without extending the service, see last code snippet.

#### Factories

```js
app.factory('SeriesFactory', function(SeriesArrayFactory, fbUrl) {
  return function() {
    const ref = new Firebase(`${fbUrl}/series`);
    return new SeriesArrayFactory(ref);
  }
});

app.factory('SeriesArrayFactory', function($firebaseArray, $q) {
  return $firebaseArray.$extend({
    findSeries: function(seriesName) {
      const deferred = $q.defer();

      // query by 'name'
      this.$ref()
        .orderByChild('name')
        .equalTo(seriesName)
        .once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            const value = dataSnapshot.val();
            deferred.resolve(value);
          } else {
            deferred.reject('Not found');
          }
        })

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  });
});
```

#### Controller

```js
app.controller('HomeController',function($scope, SeriesFactory, fbUrl) {
  $scope.seriesName = '';

  $scope.findSeries = function() {
    const seriesCollection = new SeriesFactory();

    seriesCollection
      .findSeries($scope.seriesName)
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.series = data;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
});
```

#### Without Extended Service

Here is what a controller function would look like if you weren't using the factories:

```js
$scope.findSeriesWithoutFactory = function() {
  const seriesRef = new Firebase(`${fbUrl}/series`);
  const seriesCollection = $firebaseArray(seriesRef);

  seriesCollection.$ref()
    .orderByChild('name')
    .equalTo($scope.seriesName)
    .once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
        $scope.series = dataSnapshot.val();
      } else {
        console.error('Not found.');
      }
    });
};
```

### Rules

**Note:** It's important to note that you should add `".indexOn": "name"` to your Firebase rules so that the query runs efficiently. See the [Indexing Your Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html) portion of the Firebase [Security & Rules Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) for more information. Below is an example:

```json
"yourfirebaseapp": {
  ".read": "...",
  ".write": "...",
  "series": {
    ".indexOn": "name"
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to search for a property of a property of an object ? Example: series.category.id_category ? Meaning that category is an object and I need to compare against id_category's property.