# How do I search (SELECT and WHERE) in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database like the following:

```
{
    "message" : "Hello, World!",
    "reserva" : [ null, {
        "codreserva" : 123,
        "email" : "teste@teste.com",
        "status" : "check in"
    }, {
        "codreserva" : 124,
        "email" : "fabio@ciaf.com.br",
        "status" : "check out"
    } ]
}
```

And I have code to search for the status of `reserva`:

```
public void ProcuraReserva(String codigodareserva){
    // Read from the database
    myRef = database.getReference("reserva/"+codigodareserva+"/status");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            textview1.setText("Status da reserva "+ value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        textview1.setText("Status com falha");
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming `codigodareserva == 124` I want this function to print `check out`.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code to work as expected, you need to change the data structure a little bit, like this:

```json
{
    "reserva": {
        "123": {
             "email" : "teste@teste.com",
             "status" : "check in"
        },
        "124": {
             "email" : "fabio@ciaf.com.br",
             "status" : "check out"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the right way to do it in your case, and most of the time actually. We're changing it from being an array to an object with the ids as key values.

Comment: Jaime , thanks for your help . However , it could help me as I think the codreserva with teste@teste.com email?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but you could use the email as the `reserva` key just fine, makes it easy to find a reservation based on the email you signed up with :D

Comment: Jaime Gómez, no, sorry. from the structure that you gave me. If I want to look for a CODRESERVA with my e-mail, how do I do ???

Comment: You can query for it, look at this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164753/retrieve-record-with-query-angularfire. However, what I would do is store that reference, with email as the key, in another collection, so it's easy to look it up, and update them both if something change. But this is another question, pay with queries a little and ask a new more specific question when you run into problems again :)